# Why I get ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION ( winapi error 1 ), when I execute GetFileSizeEx?

Tags: winapi

I would like to get file size of my external hard disk.

```cpp
handle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive5", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL , NULL);

if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
   std::cout<<"ERROR!"<<std::endl;
   return -1;
}

LARGE_INTEGER size;
if(!GetFileSizeEx(handle, &size))
{
    auto lastError = GetLastError();
    std::cout<<"Last Error: "<<lastError<<std::endl;
    CloseHandle(handle);
    return -1;
}
```

When I execute my application with admin rights ( it is necessary for CreateFile ), I get `Last Error: 1`.

OS: Windows 10,
Compiler: MinGW 7.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, `GetFileSizeEx()` is the wrong function to use for a "physical disk" object.

Use `DeviceIoControl()` with `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY` instead.